# Issue in printing the encode format in URL

Tags: jsp

I am encoding the color format to the url using value="${esapi:encodeForURL(WCParam.color)}". But for the German language, I am getting color=gr%C3%BCn . Due to this, the page is not getting loaded correctly.

Can any one give me any idea why this error is caused?

"Here is my code implementation. Yes it is in form and it is submitted by POST method. A blank page is coming due to the wrongly redirected URL link. The Error is with the URL link (catalog/categories/departments/living_room/10550/?color=gr%‌​c3%bcn). This is the code i am using to encode the color format"

Code:-`<c:if test="${not empty WCParam.color && '-1' ne WCParam.color && empty usedFromSearch}">

<input type="hidden" name="color" value="${esapi:encodeForURL(WCParam.color)}"/> 
</c:if>`

Comment: Show more code. Do you use it in a form? How is the form submitted (directly using GET/POST method, AJAX, ...)? What does _page is not getting loaded correctly_ mean - an error in displaying the current page, or an error after submitting the form? What error? Elaborate.

Comment: Hi, here is my code implementation. Yes it is in form and it is submitted by POST method. A blank page is coming due to the wrongly redirected URL link. The Error is with the URL link (catalog/categories/departments/living_room/10550/?color=gr%c3%bcn). This is the code i am using to encode the color format                                                                                                  <c:if test="${not empty WCParam.color && '-1' ne WCParam.color && empty usedFromSearch}">    
     <input type="hidden" name="color" value="${esapi:encodeForURL(WCParam.color)}" />
    </c:if>

Comment: Please do not add the code to comment, **edit** the question instead.

Comment: please check it now

Comment: I used decodeURI command and it is coming fine now.